# compare today's date with unix timestamp value in database

Tags: php, mysql

In database I am storing date value unix timestamp value for e.g.'1434952110' using `time()` now I am trying to compare todays value with this value as below

```
$jobpostdate = date("Y-m-d");//today's date passing in database to compare
```

**query**

```
$sql = "SELECT jsp_title, jsp_subtitle, jsp_desc, jsp_location, jsp_date ";
$sql .= "FROM js_projects WHERE DATE(jsp_date) = '$jobpostdate' ";
```

I tried above query , but even if the value is present I am getting no rows found, where i am going wrong how can I compare date values ? I know how to compare in php but i don't know exactly how to check in query ,Pls any one can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a unix timestamp in a varchar field and you can't change this.

If you compare the unix timestamp directly you will only get results that match the exact second of the timestamp.

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert the timestamp in a date value you can actually use:

```
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(jsp_date))=CURDATE()
```

This compares the date portion of the timestamp with the current date, giving you all database entries of the given day.

Note: This could create performance problems, since a lot of conversions occur on every request. You should really convert the unix timestamp in the database into a DateTime or Date field.

Comment: i was struggling to get this done but as i was having a integer column with unix timestamp inside most of the people are comparing to a timestamp column type.THANKS

Answer (score -1):

You could use PHP DateTime class.

```
$today = new DateTime('now'); // Can be what ever you want, not only now
                              // see below for reference.
$jobpostdate = $today->getTimestamp();
```

and query:

```
$sql = "SELECT jsp_title, jsp_subtitle, jsp_desc, jsp_location, jsp_date ";
$sql .= "FROM js_projects WHERE jsp_date = '$jobpostdate' ";
```

!PS I can't test it, but in a nutshell it should work.

Fore more reference about this awesome class go here:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: This is not associated with what the OP has asked for!